# Cyclic group - order of element

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

$|G|=n$ cyclic

$$n=q_1^{e_1} \cdot \dots \cdot q_k^{e_k}$$

If $g^{\frac{n}{q_i}}=1$ then $q$ is not a generator.

If $g^{\frac{n}{q_i}} \neq 1, \forall i=1, \dots , k$

$\Rightarrow q_i^{e^i} \mid ord(g), \forall i=1, \dots , k$

$\Rightarrow n=q_1^{e_1} \cdots q_k^{e_k} \mid ord(g)$

Can you explain the case $g^{\frac{n}{q_i}} \neq 1, \forall i=1, \dots , k$ ?

How do we get the conclusion that $q_i^{e^i} \mid ord(g), \forall i=1, \dots , k$ and that $n=q_1^{e_1} \cdots q_k^{e_k} \mid ord(g)$ ?

Comment: That's incredibly hard to read, and possibly incoherent; what's $q$ without a subscript? Is there any way you could add some commentary in between the lines of algebra, and maybe some motivation along the lines of what you want to prove, under what assumptions?

Comment: @pjs36 I'm guessing that $q$ should be a $g$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand what it is you are asking, but it looks like you are asking about a proof that g is a generator if and only if g^(n/q_i)≠1 for each i. So, I will go with that interpretation. I will also assume the q_i are distinct primes.

**1. Can you explain the case g^(n/q_i)≠1,∀i=1,…,k ?**

This is simply the condition of the following part of the theorem:

g^(n/q_i)≠1,∀i=1,…,k -> g is a generator

Where the full theorem being proven is:

g^(n/q_i)≠1,∀i=1,…,k <-> g is a generator

**2. How do we get the conclusion that q_i^(e^i)∣ord(g),∀i=1,…,k...**

We have that ord(g) | |G|, and also that ord(g) !| n/q_i since g^(n/q_i)≠1. n/q_i is simply n missing one factor, q_i, and since the multiset of ord(g)'s prime factors are strictly contained in the multiset of n's prime factors, the only way ord(g) could not divide n/q_i is if it had the one factor (counting multiplicity) that n/q_i is missing, namely all the q_i, or, in other words, q_i^(e^i) divides ord(g).

**3. How do we get the conclusion that... n=q_1^(e_1)⋯q_k^(e_k)∣ord(g) ?**

This is an immediate consequence of the preceding; each q_i^(e^i) divides ord(g) and so their product does also (since they are relatively prime), and it is a basic fact about groups that ord(g) | n, so n | ord(g) | n -> n=ord(g).